# Gentoo install yabootconfig loop

Tags: linux, mac, command-line, installation, gentoo

I've been installing Gentoo on an iBook G4 from the minimal cd.  The install seemed to be working perfectly, until I came to "Configuring the Bootloader" in the handbook.  I followed all of the steps up to entering yabootconfig.  Yabootconfig informed me that it could not find the kernel, and asked me to provide the path.  Unfortunately, I don't know the path.  I could easily find it out if I could exit yabootconfig, but no matter what I type, it invariably returns to "Enter path to a kernel image (not including chroot):"  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Control** + **C** will terminate *yabootconfig*, and your kernel will be in **/boot/**. Assuming you followed the handbook fully.

Comment: You're welcome, nice to see the **gentoo** tag on here.